# Why is QThread::finished signal not being emitted?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency, qthread

I've created my own `TestService` which runs on a separate `QThread`, but when the `MainLoop` terminates the `QThread::finished` signal does not get emitted. I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946209/qthreadfinished-is-never-emitted), but the problem was slightly different there because the OP was overloading `QThread` whereas I simply move my class to the thread.

Note that **I do not overload** the `QThread` class, I only overload `QObject` based on this example: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Here is my `TestService` class:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class TestService: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
private:
    volatile int _count;
    QWaitCondition _monitor;
    QMutex _mutex;
    QThread* _thread;

public:
    TestService(int numSeconds)
    {
        _count = numSeconds;
        _thread = NULL;
        cout << "TestService()" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~TestService()
    {
        cout << "~TestService()" << endl;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&_mutex);
        if(_thread == NULL)
        {
            _thread = new QThread;

            // Move this service to a new thread
            this->moveToThread(_thread);

            // The main loop will be executed when the thread
            // signals that it has started.
            connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(MainLoop()));

            // Make sure that we notify ourselves when the thread
            // is finished in order to correctly clean-up the thread.
            connect(_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(OnFinished()));

            // The thread will quit when the sercives
            // signals that it's finished.
            connect(this, SIGNAL(Finished()), _thread, SLOT(quit()));

            // The thread will be scheduled for deletion when the 
            // service signals that it's finished
            connect(this, SIGNAL(Finished()), _thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

            // Start the thread
            _thread->start();
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        _count = 0;
        _monitor.wakeAll();
    }
private slots:
    void MainLoop()
    {
        cout << "MainLoop() Entered" << endl;
        while(_count > 0)
        {
            cout << "T minus " << _count << " seconds." << endl;

            QMutexLocker locker(&_mutex);
            _monitor.wait(&_mutex, 1000);
            _count--;
        }
        cout << "MainLoop() Finished" << endl;
        emit Finished();
    }

    virtual void OnFinished()
    {
        cout << "OnFinished()" << endl;
    }
signals:
    void Finished();
};
```

Here is the testing code:

```
void ServiceTest()
{
    cout << "Press q to quit." << endl;
    cout << "Press s to start." << endl;
    cout << "Press t to stop." << endl;
    QSharedPointer<TestService> testService(new TestService(10));
    char in = 'a';
    while( in != 'q' )
    {
        switch(tolower(in))
        {
        case 's':
            testService->Start();
            break;
        case 't':
            testService->Stop();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        cin.get(in);
        in = tolower(in);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ServiceTest();

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &a, SLOT(quit()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output is:

```
Press q to quit.
Press s to start.
Press t to stop.
TestService()
s
MainLoop() Entered
T minus 10 seconds.
T minus 9 seconds.
T minus 8 seconds.
t
MainLoop() Finished
q
~TestService()
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Could anybody explain why is `finished` not being emitted how I can fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Signal finished() gets emitted of cause, but you don't catch it.

Here:

```
connect(_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(OnFinished()));
```

`Qt::QueuedConnection` is used, as `_thread` and `this` (service) are in different threads.

By the time `finished()` is emitted, `_thread`'s event loop already finished executing, so signal will not be delivered to the slot.

You can explicitly use `Qt::DirectConnection`.

*EDIT:*

QTherad works like this:

```
QThread::start()
{
    emit started();
    run();
    emit finished();
}

QThread::run()
{
     eventloop->exec();
}
```

So, by the time `finished` is emitted, eventloop already stop execution. And as you move `service` to `_thread`, service's event loop is `_thread` event loop.

Note, that `QObject` itself has no its own event loop. Event loops are created by dialogs, threads and application.

---

Actually I will recommend in your simple case just use [`QtConcurent::run`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/threads-qtconcurrent.html), as you do not perform actual event processing in the new thread, but just run single function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, my situation is slightly different as my `TestService` does not overload `QThread`- it only overloads `QObject`. The example I based my code on is here: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ Regarding the `QtConcurrent::run`, I would prefer not to use boost for this example because I'm strictly trying to stick to Qt libraries only.

Comment: @Lirik, sorry I misread the post: "move _it_ to thread" was interpreted as "move _thread_ to thread" (that is not better than subclassing). I edited my answer.

Comment: @Lirik, also note, `QtConcurent::run` is full Qt and have noting to do with boost.

Comment: I just noticed that the example in `QtCurrent::run` uses `boost::bind`. **Thanks for the updated answer**: what I'm still confused about is what you mean when you say that when `finished()` is emitted, the `_thread`'s event loop is already finished executing... I'm not trying to process it in the `_thread`'s event loop, but in the `TestService`'s event loop. **If I understand things correctly**, the `TestService` event loop should still be active, since the service has not been destroyed.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification... now it makes sense! And I also just saw the other ways to use `QtConcurrent::run` without `boost::bind`, I'll try to find a way to fix this.

Comment: `QtConcurrent::run` was a great solution! Thanks!

Comment: How does the `QThread::started()` signal get processed even though he has no event loop going? It should be `Qt::QueuedConnection` just like the `QThread::finished()` connection. By the same reasoning, QThread::started() never should have processed.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized that the receiver of the `QThread::finished()` signal is the object that's on a thread with no event loop, so his problem was that the slot was never triggered, not that the signal never emitted.